# $\arccos$ and $\arctan$ equation

Tags: trigonometry

I cannot understand this strange equation:

> $$\arccos(\xi)=\arctan\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{1-\xi^2}}{\xi}\right)$$

Comment: First, for which real numbers $\xi$ both sides of the equation make sense? Next, for which of those $\xi$ are they equal?

Comment: They are equal for all real numbers

Comment: Take the $\cos()$ of each side

Comment: The right side is not defined at $0$ and if we want to keep in real analysis neither at any number with an absolute value greater than $1$.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici What do i get? I have already tried but i can't understand

Comment: @A. Rossi No! First, $\xi$ must be in $[-1,1]$ and different of $0$ for both sides to make sense. Next, $\arccos(\xi) = \alpha$ is equivalent to $\cos \alpha = \xi$ AND $\alpha \in [0,\pi]$.

Comment: Assume that $\xi \in [-1,1] \setminus \{0\}$. Let $\alpha = \arctan(\sqrt{1-\xi^2}/\xi)$. What do you know about $\alpha$? To which interval belongs to $\alpha$? What is its tangent? What can you deduce about its cosine?

Comment: @Christophe Leuridan Ok understood, but i cannot understand how this equation still work

Comment: Hint: Draw a right triangle with an acute angle $\theta$ and adjacent side $\xi$ and hypotenuse $1$. Now isn't $\theta=\arccos(\xi)$? Can you write $\theta$ in term of $\arctan$ ?

Comment: If $-1 \le \xi <0$, then $\arctan(\sqrt{1-\xi^2}/\xi)$ is in $]-\pi/2,0[$, so it cannot be equal to $\arccos(\xi)$, which belongs to $|0,\pi]$ and more precisely to $]\pi/2,\pi]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint : To show this, you can see that their derivatives are equals on certains open connected sets. Therefore, these functions are equals up to an additive constant on these sets. Replace by some points to find that the constants are zero.

Comment: It does work, but it requires more calculus.

Comment: Well it's another approach effectively longer here, but I think it's good to know this approach is possible, maybe to transfer it to another problem where it's quicker :-)

Comment: Yes, it also interesting. But for example, it proves without explaining simply why $\arctan(t)+\arctan(1/t) = \mathrm{sign}(t)\pi/2$ for all $t \in \mathbf{R}_+^*$.